# jQuery filter span by property value

Tags: jquery, requiredfieldvalidator

I am attempting to only query the Page_Validators that have an isvalid property set to false. I tried using

```
$(Page_Validators).filter('span[isvalid=true]')
```

but it does not return any results. Strangely when I query a validator by id

```
$(Page_Validators).filter('span[id$=bob]')
```

it works. What is up with the isvalid property and why can I not query by it?

As requested here is the markup for one of the validators

```
<span class="detail-required-validator" id="ctl00_MainContent_Service_Name_Validator" style="visibility: visible;">*</span>
```

this totally makes sense now, there is no isvalid attribute in the markup. The Page_Validators object is an array of javascript representations of the above markup. so would I need $.grep?

Comment: Can you post the HTML sample as well?

Comment: what happens when you change `span[isvalid=true]` to `span[isvalid=false]`?

Comment: Does `$(Page_Validators).filter('span[isvalid]')` produce any results?

Comment: @cyberbit no, no results for $(Page_Validators).filter('span[isvalid]') as well.

Comment: @imvain2 same result whether true or false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the answer is to use $.grep because I am querying a javaScript array and not an array of span elements!

```
var validators = $.grep(Page_Validators, function (n)
{
    return n.isvalid == false;
});
```

The above code returns an array of asp.net RequiredFieldValidators that have controls with invalid inputs (if any)